# tool for time measurement of csv file to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, performance, csv, time

I have written a python script which import CSV file in MySQL db. I need to check the speed of read/write to MySQL because I need to optimzed the speed and time. I search and find this command

```
time ./royshah.py
```

which gives results like this

```
real    0m2.579s
user    0m0.448s
sys     0m0.192s
```

my file size is 86 kb and it consists of 1200 rows and columns are 9. my question is

```
is there any other command or useful profiling tool for python and MySQL
to measure more precisely speed  time other than
this command "time ./file-name" ?
```

I tried my best to find one but unable to find. 
thanx for the help.

Comment: what you really need is LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: @e4c5 I know about LOAD DATA INFILE and also about multiple row insertions.  . I look here at SO  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495162/speed-up-inserting-large-datasets-from-txt-file-to-mysql-using-python and some sites. I am just asking for command other than "time ./filename" to measure time accurately.

Comment: @e4c5 Speed improvement is not an issue. I can use multiple rows insertions or data load infile. .I ask for guidance regarding time measurement. thanx

Comment: asking for external resources happens to be off topic

Comment: Less than a minute with my favorite search engine turned up some MySQL profiling tools. You can probably find the same sort of information.  Probably the most important aspects of MySQL bulk-load performance are database server machine load average (cpu) and database IO channel (disk drive) saturation.   Your sample dataset is probably a factor of 100 too small to measure those values with any precision. 500 rows per second is pretty good performance, especially if you haven't optimized it at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanx for such a useful link.

Comment: @e4c5 thanx for the hint. I will be careful in future. .

Comment: @O.Jones I have a dataset which consist of 3 millions rows and size is 14 GB. .Thanx for giving the information regarding Bulk-load performance. I will took them into account when dealing with this large dataset soon. I am really thankful for the help .

Comment: I instrument the program with microsecond timers before and after commands.  (I don't know the python specifics.)